# Remove elements by index from a string within numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following example array with strings:

```
 ['100000000' '101010100' '110101010' '111111110']
```

I would like to be able to remove some elements by index in each of the strings in the array simultaneously. For example if I will remove elements with index 6 and 8, I should receive the following outcome:

```
 ['1000000' '1010110' '1101000' '1111110']
```

All my attempts failed so far maybe because the string is immutable, but am not sure whether I have to convert and if so - to what and how.

Comment: You have to use string slicing and assign the results back to the array elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(['100000000', '101010100', '110101010', '111111110'])

list(map(lambda s: "".join([c for i, c in enumerate(str(s)) if i not in {5, 7}]), a))
```

Returns:

```
['1000000', '1010110', '1101000', '1111110']
```

Comment: Iterating over a list is faster than iterating over a numpy array: Just mapping `a.tolist()` instead of `a` reduces runtime (~30% for this array) to 5.36 µs ± 52.3 ns per loop from 7.52 µs ± 170 ns

Comment: It provides the same outcome as in the examples, but I am trying to point elements to be removed by index. In this case why we are putting 5 and 7 instead of 7 and 8?

Comment: Python lists start with index 0, so if you want to remove 6th and 8th, that's indexes 5 and 7. If this doesn't solve your whole problem, try to describe what you imagine the final output should be. This example gives the output you indicated.

Comment: It can also take this syntax - ```list(map(lambda s: "".join(c for i, c in enumerate(str(s), 1) if i not in {6, 8}), a))```     Note: skip ```[]```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to convert `a` into a 2D array of single characters, mask out the values you don't want, and then convert back into a 1D array of strings.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(['100000000', '101010100', '110101010', '111111110'])

b = a.view('U1').reshape(*a.shape, -1)

mask = np.ones(b.shape[-1], dtype=bool)
mask[[5, 7],] = False

b = b[:, mask].reshape(-1).view(f'U{b.shape[-1] - (~mask).sum()}')
```